# Execute external program with specific parameters from windows c/c++ code

Tags: c, windows, parameters

I want to call Program1 from Program2 with exact same parameters which I called Program2 with. 
In Linux, I can do it like this:

```
int main(char argc, char* argv[]){
execv("./Program1", argv); 
}
```

In windows, I tried [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

but as the first post says there is potential issue: "argv[0] Doesn't Contain the Module Name as Expected". I do want to send proper argv[0] to Program1. What should I do?

Comment: On Windows, it's called [`_execv`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/886kc0as.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

argv[0] is the name of the program itself.

You should do :

```
int main(char argc, char **argv)
{
  char* argvForProgram1[] = { "./Program1", 0 }
  execv(argvForProgram1[0], argvForProgram1);
}
```

or to keep your previous args :

```
int main(char argc, char **argv)
{
  char** argvForProgram1 = argv;
  argvForProgram1[0] = "./Program1";
  execv(argvForProgram1[0], argvForProgram1);
}
```

Using `execve` is better too because you keep the environment:

```
int main(char argc, char **argv, char **envp)
{
  char** argvForProgram1 = argv;
  argvForProgram1[0] = "./Program1";
  execve(argvForProgram1[0], argvForProgram1, envp);
}
```

Comment: My bad. I thought execv is linux-specific function, but it is POSIX.