# How to open a bmp image file from C program

Tags: c, file-io, bmp

What I want it not the normal `fopen()` function. I want to open the image, as in, when I double click on the image, then the way it opens in the imageViewer. I want to open it like that.

Is there any way of doing that through a C code? So basically I want it to pop open and view itself.

I am on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends of the `imageViewer` program.

If the `imageViewer` program could be called in this way in your linux command line interface

```
$imageViewer myfile.bmp
```

then in your C code you can use system to open your file with `imageViewer` program

```
system("imageViewer myfile.bmp");
```

Comment: Is this above C code line, a system call? Is this how the system call works? i.e. call the application you want to open  + the file name to open?

Comment: the system will only allow to execute external commands. so if your file could be opened with your imageviewer program via linux command then you can use system

Comment: system() is a "system call", but it do not have anything to do with the name "system". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call

Answer (score 1):

The question could be "how to call an extern program" (see e.g [Execute external program with specific parameters from windows c/c++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110445/execute-external-program-with-specific-parameters-from-windows-c-c-code) ) or how to use a specific library/framework in order to "read" a bmp file, open a gfx window and "map" the image on that window; being on Ubuntu (with GNOME?) you can do it easily (and beyond simple BMP), somethings like e.g. https://developer.gnome.org/gnome-devel-demos/stable/image-viewer.c.html

Comment: though "from windows" in title, the solution works elsewhere and there's an example for "Linux"; other Q on SO liekly answer the question better than this one I've picked on the fly)